# Site User Web App not updating permission group

Tags: web-part, permissions

I am fairly new to sharepoint and having a real time with this. I have a collaboration site that features the **Site User** Web Part to show who is a member of the committee. It is populated using the permission group.

I am trying to rebuild this as a publishing site and when I run the Web Part with the same permission group on the publishing site, it shows an outdated version of the group, with  individuals who are no longer on the committee appearing.

Any idea on what might be causing this?